# Can I convert a boolean or a primitive into an observable?

Tags: javascript, observable

I have a javascript function which returns an boolean in some cases or an Observable in some other cases. Can I somehow always return an Observable by 
creating Observable out of a boolean?

Comment: can you create a plunker to reproduce the use case.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want the rxjs .of() method (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/of.md) so you can return a observable that emits a boolean

```
return Observable.of(boolean);
```

Comment: I also needed  import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'; at the top of my component.

Answer (score 3):

Addition to the accepted answer, the return **of(data)** (and not `Observable.of(data)`) is enough for `RxJS 6` and `Angular 12`.